# java executing maven project outside IDE

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

i might have completely missundestood how maven works, but i have the following issue.
i created an application with maven in netbeans. it runs in netbeans fine, but when i make Clean and Build it just compiles my source files, and the maven dependendencies are not in the jar file, so cannot run in command window.

this is my pom file. it has build section, the dependencies are in the classpath of mainfest.mf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ibh</groupId>
<artifactId>SafePassword</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.ibh.safepassword.TestMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.192</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

i came from c# world, thought maven is similar than NuGet which is playing the game only in DEV phase, but at compile time everything is there ...

what is missing? how to execute the jar file to have the other dependencies in place and so the app can run?

thanks for your hints!

EDIT

i don't agree that this question is fully duplicated to the one you're referring to.
as i can read these many solutions maven is quite complicated, there is no ONE solution for every issue

Comment: unzip the jar. the dependencies should be inside. you can run the jar with `java -jar <jarname>`

Comment: Sean Patrick Floyd: i checked the contents of the jar, no dependencies there. also when executing the jar in command window get NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 1):

By default Maven builds a jar that is basically a library - it doesn't contain its dependencies. If you want to include dependencies, making a runnable application, you have two main options:

1. Bundle everything in that one jar using some plugin that allows it, such as [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). You can then run this jar.
2. Create a distribution bundle with your jar and all dependencies:

   1. Use packaging that is designed to be a distribution, such as `war` or `ear` - if one of them matches your intent
   2. Otherwise use generic bundling plugin, such as standard [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or even more advanced [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Of course, you still need to have manifest file with main class and classpath, but you have already done that correctly.